# How can I recall a object inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone Classic
        NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
    }
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];



ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController *container = [ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController
                                                      containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                      leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}
```

I want some value in leftMenuViewController, whenever I change my controller, but it loads only one time as didFinishLaunchingWithOptions loads once as app launches.
So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a property.

In your AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController *container;
```

In your AppDelegate.m file:

```
self.container = [ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController
                  containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                  leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then when you'd like to change the leftMenuViewController, you can call the following from anywhere you'd like:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.container setLeftMenuViewController:...someViewController];
```

There is a good intro to properties in [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Also, you should be using `if...` `else...` rather than two if statements when checking for the size:

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 480.0f)
{
    // iPhone Classic
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
}
else if(result.height == 568.0f)
{
    // iPhone 5
    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
}
```

Comment: Let me check,but won't it create new controller over previous controller?

Comment: No, it won't because you're storing the container you've already created and then editing that instance rather than re-creating it.

Comment: SideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuViewController;
    
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];

Comment: I did this in my another controller, but the gesture i set over it, got vanished.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, and that's not part of the question - a new question should be created for that query.

Comment: leftSideMenuViewController, I want to change one NSString value in this controller and reload it, so that I could get my desired output that on which screen what side menu should show

Comment: So store that NSString as a property of leftSideMenuViewController, and change it when you want to by going through your AppDelegate and accessing the instance of leftSideMenuViewController

Comment: I agree with your way, but that is not exactly what I tried to do, however I do upvote you and accept it, but still I am in maze

Comment: Thank you. if you still can't work it out, open a new question and somebody will help you.

Comment: I can change variable but It won't reload or you can say call ViewDidLoad o LeftSideMenuViewController, so that changing are useless till we reload that particular table in leftMenuViewController

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008607/change-value-of-nsstring-in-a-controller-which-is-created-in-didfinishlaunchingw