# Change value of NSString in a controller which is created in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and reload that controller

Tags: ios

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(result.height == 480)
{
    // iPhone Classic
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
}
if(result.height == 568)
{
    // iPhone 5
    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
}
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];



ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController *container = [ContainerOfSideMenuByVeerViewController
                                                  containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                  leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}
```

I want to change the value of NSString which is present in leftMenuViewController and reload it, so that I can change logic according to new data.

I want to change that NSString in every controller, but I am unable to do as leftMenuViewController starts in didFinishLauchingWithOption which loads only one time.

How can I do that?

Comment: will you please make you question more descriptive. Whats your requirement?

Comment: You need to make this more clear; what is exactly do you want to happen? Are you trying to update UI after changing an `NSString`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `refresh` Method in `leftMenuViewController` or make `property` of your `NSString`.
Define SideMenuViewController`*leftMenuViewController in`Appdelegate`file and make it`property`,`synthesize`it. Now you are able to refresh your`leftMenuViewController`with your`NSString` with this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[appDelegate.leftMenuViewController refresh:yourStr];
```

Comment: Change `AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication];` to `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: It will not refresh the controller, or reload it, but it will just simply change the value of one variable in leftViewController, but I want to change that variable along with reload contain, simply wana call its ViewDidLoad again, clear ?

Comment: Thanks.I will use shared object, But what about my real problem?

Comment: Than write your code in applicationWillEnterForeground method